# sfPropelPager reduce queries

Tags: mysql, symfony1, propel

i'm working in a symfony project and using sfPropelPager to show a paged list of elements.
The problem is that with a great amount of data to list (i.e. thousands of registers) it makes **a query to the database for each page to show!!!!** That means about 100 extra queries in my case, and that is unacceptable.

Showing some of my code: the function that returns the pager object

```
$pager = new sfPropelPager('MyTable',sfConfig::get('sfPropelPagerLines'));
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add('my_table_field',$value);
$c->addDescendingOrderByColumn('date');
$pager->setCriteria($c);
$pager->init();
return $pager;
```

So, please, if you know a way to get all the results with only one query, it would be a great solution for my problem. Otherwise i must implement that list with an ajax call for every page the user wants to see

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i did'nt get a solution for the problem, i had to implement the list via `AJAX` call, calling to a function that returns the requested page, so at the load of the page, no query for this list is slowing the user experience.

Thank you anyway to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to get your problem but, anyway, avoid the use of `Criteria`. Try to make queries with the `ModelCriteria` API: http://www.propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html.

For each paginated page, a query to the database will be done, this is the standard behavior for all pagers I know. If it's related to related objects (assuming you want to display information from relations), you may want to create a query that links those objects before to paginate, that way you'll get one query per page for all your data to display.
Read this doc for instance: http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html#query_termination_methods

Comment: My problem is that with a big amount of data, the pager does an unacceptable number of queries, when obviously could make only one, and build the pager object with the results of that query. I'm asking if `sfPropelPager` can do it. Nothing to do with the criteria system

Comment: 300 queries for a simple test table, with a fraction of the information that will store in the future. To be more specific, i'm using the page to show a list of log entries. This list will grow a lot in the future, so if now i have 300 queries only in development environment, in 3-6 months in production probably i'll have 1000000+ queries!!! obviously unacceptable